# Model not training properly accuracy is constant while training a rgb image dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-cloud-ml

I am training a model on fruits360 dataset from kaggle. 
I have 0 dense layers, and 3 convolutional layers in my keras model.  My input shape is (60,60,3) as the images are loaded in rgb format. please help me to troubleshoot what is the problem with this model why is it not training properly. I've tried with different combinations of layers but the accuracy and loss remains constant no matter whatever you change.

following is the model:

```
dense_layers = [0]
layer_sizes = [64]
conv_layers = [3]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
for layer_size in layer_sizes:
    for conv_layer in conv_layers:
        NAME = "{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
        print(NAME)

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3), input_shape=(60, 60, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        for l in range(conv_layer-1):
            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3)))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Flatten())

        for _ in range(dense_layer):
            model.add(Dense(layer_size))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))

        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

        tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/")

        model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'],
                      )

        model.fit(X_norm, y,
                  batch_size=32,
                  epochs=10,
                  validation_data=(X_norm_test,y_test),
                  callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

but the accuracy remains constant as follows:

```
Epoch 1/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 641us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 2/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 638us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 3/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 637us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 4/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 635us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 5/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 635us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 6/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 631us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 7/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 631us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 8/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 631us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 9/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 635us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
Epoch 10/10
42798/42798 [==============================] - 27s 626us/step - loss: nan - acc: 0.0115 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0114
```

what can I do to train this model properly. To increase the accuracy.

Comment: You certainly don't seem to have 0 dense layers as you say. Not sure why you build your model in such a confusing manner - are you really initializing a `model=Sequential()` in every loop iteration? Please add to your post: 1) the `model.summary()` result 2) the number of classes 3) a link to the dataset

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct *indentation*?? Please be sure to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is a proper loss for an output with only 1 unit.

Notice your loss is `nan`. This means there is a mathematical error in your model/data/loss somewhere. Many times this is caused by division by zero, overflowing numbers, etc.

I suppose you should be using `'binary_crossentropy'` as a loss function.

Notice that you will still have a risk of frozen losses because of 'relu' activations. If this happens, you can add `BatchNormalization()` layers before the `Activation('relu')` layers.

---

Please take into account @desertnaut's comments. You're creating a new `Sequential` model inside every loop.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is with the last dense layer. It is set to one (i.e., one class). The Fruits-360 dataset (depending on the version) has upwards of a 100 classes. The 1% accuracy is also another giveaway. The labels from the training set have 100 different values. A dense layer of one output node can only (randomly) get it right 1 out of a 100 -- hence the 1%.

The 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' is okay as long as the labels are not one-hot encoded. If so, you should use 'categorical_crossentropy'. The Fruits-360 dataset when used with Adam tends not to converge at high learning rates (like 0.1 and 0.01), best to set the learning rate low to something between 0.001 and 0.0001.